# Kendo-grid-checkbox-column generates duplicate empty columns in kendo-grid angular

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, angular13

I utilize the "kendo-grid-checkbox-column" to craft a custom selection checkbox within a Kendo Grid in Angular. However, after performing operations such as sorting, grouping, or reordering, I've observed that upon refreshing the page, a new empty column is appended to the Kendo Grid[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APPaG.png)

```
   ` <kendo-grid-checkbox-column
      *ngIf="showSelectBox"
      [title]="title"
      [width]="width"
      [showSelectAll]="showSelectAll"
      [columnMenu]="false"
    >
      <ng-template *ngIf="showSelectAll" kendoGridHeaderTemplate
       let-dataItem >
       <div class="select-all-checkbox">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          [checked]="isSelectedAll"
          [disabled]="dataItem.disabled"
          (click)="selectionSelectAllBox($event, dataItem)"
        />
        <span>Select</span>
      </div>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem
        let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          [checked]="dataItem.selected"
          [disabled]="dataItem.disabled"
          (click)="selectionChangeCheckbox($event, dataItem, rowIndex)"
        />
      </ng-template>

  </kendo-grid-checkbox-column>`
```

I attempted to override "kendoColumns" with my initial "kendoColumns," and although it partially resolved the issue, there remains a brief moment during loading where empty columns are visible before disappearing.

My goal is to prevent any dynamic columns from being added to the grid upon page refresh, specifically those generated by "kendo-grid-checkbox-column.